# In Xamarin Forms, how to size an image within a grid cell?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms-styles

can't figure out how to make an image smaller than its container within a grid.

I.e. if I want a square image to be 50% of the size square grid cell and centered within the cell, how can I do that?

Comment: did you get that?

Answer (score 0):

Try by setting HorizontalOptions and VerticalOptions property for Image view as follow,

```
Image imageView = new ImageView;
imageView.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand (or) LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand
imageView.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand (or) LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand
```

Also, try by setting Aspect property for Image view,

```
imageView.Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit
```

Comment: I don't understand how that would result in the image not filling the entire grid cell.

Answer (score 0):

Either

1. you set a WidthRequest, HeightRequest, HorizontalOptions="Center" and VerticalOptions="Center" on your image (but this requires a fixed image size)
2. or you define another Grid into your parent grid cell. The new (child) grid can define 3 rows "Star" and 3 columns "Star" and your image fills the centered cell. The advantage is that your image can be of any size. It will adapt its size to the screen.